# PHP loading structed files faster

Tags: php, database, serialization

I have multiple dataset as below, and I want to handle them using PHP.

```
Dataset #1 (75 cols * 27,000 rows)
          col #1 col #2 ...
record #1
record #2
...

Dataset #2 (32 cols * 7,500 rows)
....

Dataset #3 (44 cols * 17,500 rows)
....
```

Here, the number of records and columns are **different** so it is hard to use database structure.
And note that each 'cell' of dataset is only consists of either real number or N/A... and the dataset is perfectly **fixed**, i.e., there will be no any change.

So what I've done so far is make them as a file-based table, and write a starting offset of each record in the file.
Using this way, quite nice access speedup was achieved, but not satisfactory so far, because an access to each record requires *parsing it as PHP data structure*.

What I ultimately want to achieve is eliminating the parsing step. But *serialization* was not a good choice because it loads **entire dataset**. Of course it is possible to serialize each record and keep their offset as I've done but without serialization, but it seems me to not so *fancy*.

So here's the question, is there any method to load a part of dataset *without* any parsing step, but more better than the partial serialization what I suggested?

Many thanks in advance.

- More information

Maybe I made the viewers a little bit confused.
Each dataset is **separated** and they exist as independent files.

Usual data access pattern is row-wise. Each row have unique ID by string, and an ID in one dataset could be exists in other dataset, but not necessarily. But above of that, what I concern is accelerating an access speed when I have some query to fetch specific row(s) in the dataset. For example, let there is a dataset like below.

```
Dataset #1 (plain-text file)
     obs1  obs2  obs3  ...
my1  3.72  5.28  10.22 ...
xu1  3.44  5.82  15.33 ...
...
qq7  8.24  10.22 47.54 ...
```

And there is a corresponding index file, serialized using PHP. A key of each item represents unique ID in the dataset, and their value represents their offset in the file

```
Index #1 (PHP-serialized one, not same as actual serialized one)
Array (
  "my1" => 0,
  "xu1" => 337,
  ...
  "qq7" => 271104
)
```

So it is possible to know record "xu1" starts at 337 bytes from the beginning of dataset file.
In order to access and fetch some rows using their unique ID,

```
1) Load serialized index file
2) Find matching IDs with query
3) Access to those position and fetch rows, and parsing them as an array of PHP.
```

The problems what I have is

```
1) Since I using exact matching, it is impossible to fetch multiple rows that partially matching with query (for example, fetch "xu1" row from query "xu")
2) Even though I indexed dataset, fetch speed is not satisfactory (took 0.05 sec. from single query)
3) When I tried to solve above problem by serializing an entire dataset, (maybe of course) the loading speed become substantially slower.
```

The only easiest way to solve above problems is make them as database I would do so,
but hope to find better way as keep them with plain text or some text-like format (for example, serialized or json-coded).

Many thanks and interests about my problem!

Comment: Do you have a large number of datasets? If you don't could you just create a table for each dataset?

Comment: Can you talk more to your data access patterns?  What do the columns in the data sets represent?  Is there any column in each data set that would be a key type of a column or one that would be used for lookup typically?  What is the total size of the data?  Are these data tables related at all (i.e. do you need to do relational lookups)?

Comment: @steven I have around 100 dataset, and their row and column # are all different. Since it is continuously increasing, it is hard to maintain all of them as a table of database. I would do so if it is the only way to achieve my goal, but I avoid that as possible.

Comment: @MikeBrant Each dataset is partially linked each other. Each record(row in my dataset) have unique ID by string, and multiple dataset can be linked if they have shared unique ID. Usual dataset size varying from (8 columns * 500 rows) to (300 columns * 30,000 rows) so it is hard to say how large it is, but around 7 MiB per dataset, in a plain-text format. The relational lookups might be needed, but not so necessarily.

Data access pattern is **almost** mainly per-row. Dataset is indexed row-wise, and access is also row-wise (but usually not sequentially). That is why I used plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question to some extent. You've got 3 sets of data, that can be or cannot be related, with different number of columns and rows.

This may not the most cleanest looking solution, but I think it could solve the purpose. You can use mysql to store the data to avoid parsing the file every now and again. You can store the data in three tables or put them in one table with all the columns (the rows without need for a set column can have "null" for the field value).

You can also use sql unions, in case you want to run queries on all the three datasets collectively, by using tricks like

```
select null as "col1", col2, col3 from table1 where col2="something"
union all
select col1,null as "col2", null as "col3" from table2 where co1="something else"
order by col1
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I think it is hard to apply to my case since I have more than 100 dataset at this point and they are still increasing. But many thanks about your solution.